# numpy > comparation vs serial > comparation with itertools.islice

Tags: python, numpy, boolean

I have a csv file with 3 columns of values.
i need to get n rows from the columns sequentally to operate on them

after getting the n rows, i need to do a > and < comparation on each of the columns from this sub-stack of the csv file.

I am using itertools.islice to get the n rows everytime so i forcefully need to use a for loop.

I was wondering if it was faster to stack the n rows first and then use the >,< comparation using numpy rather than doing using the >,< comparation for each of the rows.

Comment: Please show us what you are doing now so we can understand the process you are executing.

Comment: Do your groups of n rows overlap, or not?  Are columns all numbers (e.g. floats)?  How big of a file (total number of rows)?